# Select multiple references in form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a MenuPizza model connect with a join table to a ToppingsModel:

```
class MenuPizza < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pizza_toppings
  has_many :toppings, through: :pizza_toppings
end

class PizzaTopping < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :menu_pizza
  belongs_to :topping
end

class Topping < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :menu_pizzas, through: :pizza_toppings

  has_many :pizza_toppings, inverse_of: :topping
end
```

When a user goes to create a new MenuPizza, they should be able to select a topping from a drop down list containing all the toppings already in the database. They should be able to do this for multiple toppings.

```
= form_for @menu_pizza do |f|
  - if @menu_pizza.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2 = pluralize(@menu_pizza.errors.count, 'error') prohibted this post from being saved

  .field
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_area :name

    = f.label :description
    = f.text_area :description

    = f.select(:topping_ids, @toppings)

    = f.submit 'Add Toppings', name: 'add-toppings'
```

My question is, how do I submit multiple references to the toppings? I tried:

```
= f.select(:topping_ids, @toppings)
= f.select(:topping_ids, @toppings)
```

But that only submits the last topping selected.

Comment: Can't you use a list with all toppings and select the ones you want with checkboxes?

Comment: Yes... that makes more sense. Thank you!